# Check whether user is log in when open Android App

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication, sharedpreferences

I build a Android app which can let user log in, using `SharedPreferences` for storing user session.

I want to checking whether user session exist in when App start, my current solution is: When user open app, will enter a `EntryActivity`. If user's session is valid in `SharedPreferences`, then I start another `MainActivity` for main content. Otherwise, I open a `SignUpActivity`.

Is there any other ways or common pattern to achieve this goal?

Comment: @chanbenny : This is `standard` or `current` or `common` pattern for check login in android..!!!

Comment: This is the way to do it. But you can always modify and improve its implementation. In general, the concept remains the same

Comment: If you are developing a commercial application and you have the budget, there are built in authentication libraries, such as Microsoft Azure authentication library, available also for the mobile. That way, you can provide better protection for less work. If you're developing a client-server app and you don't want to use an external library, send the answer to the login details and have the server authenticate and return a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your splash activity:

```
if(prefs.getBoolean("isUserLogin", false)){
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }else{
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
```

Comment: Yeah this is the standard way to this and if you want to track it from your server side too then you can make web service for that too.